# (oracle) select result'length more than max length

Tags: string, oracle11g

question description:
I use plsql to execute a sql :the sql return a string that length more than 1W,
for example:

```
SELECT 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'||....||'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' FROM dual
```

because there exists so many contents to join,so it will return a string and it length more than the max length ,and plsql donnot display the result.

who can help me solve this problem ?

Comment: Solve what problem? SQL cannot return a string longer than the max length, so what you described doesn't make sense. In any case, if you have some sort of problem with long strings, use the CLOB data type (and use it correctly). If you need more help you will need to provide a better explanation/description of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show the results into rows: Write your query like :

```
select substr(your_string,1,50) from dual
union all
select substr(your_string,50,100) from dual
union all
select substr(your_string,100,...so on) from dual
```